# Combining SQL SUM clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, geographic-distance

I have a script that requires executing four rather large MySQL queries on the same subset of data. Is there a way to combine them into one query?

Here is what the query looks like:

```
Select sum(value) From 
    ( Select lat, lng, value From `pop_geo_199` Where (
         (lat Between 38.1768916977 And 39.6131083023) And (lng Between -77.9596650363 And -76.1143349637)) 
        ) As FirstCut 
Where (acos(0.627895140732*sin(radians(lat)) + 0.778297945677*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-(-1.34454929586))) * 6371 < 79.85)
```

As you can probably tell, this is a geographic query of latitude and longitude points. What the query does is first create a simple square subset of the total table (`FirstCut`), and then runs the trig functions on that to get a circular area.

From what I can tell, the part of the query that is slow is the `FirstCut`, because the table it is drawing on has some 2.8 million rows. `FirstCut`, though, in this instance, only has about 27,922 rows, so the trig part goes super fast by comparison.

The issue is, I have to run a few of these. They can all use the same `FirstCut`, though, since they are different radii centered on the same area. I'd love to be able to pull this off with just one query instead of four.

Here is what a second query looks like:

```
Select sum(value) From 
    ( Select lat, lng, value From `pop_geo_199` Where (
         (lat Between 38.1768916977 And 39.6131083023) And (lng Between -77.9596650363 And -76.1143349637)) 
        ) As FirstCut 
Where (acos(0.627895140732*sin(radians(lat)) + 0.778297945677*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-(-1.34454929586))) * 6371 < 48.57)
```

As you can see it is exactly the same as the other one except the last WHERE clause is slight different — the condition is just a smaller radii (48.57 instead of 79.85).

How can I combine these two queries into one query in an efficient way?

I've tried using CASE clauses -- is this the best approach?

```
Select 

sum(case when (acos(0.627895140732*sin(radians(lat)) + 0.778297945677*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-(-1.34454929586))) * 6371 < 79.85) then value else 0 end),

sum(case when (acos(0.627895140732*sin(radians(lat)) + 0.778297945677*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-(-1.34454929586))) * 6371 < 48.57) then value else 0 end)

From ( Select lat, lng, value From `pop_geo_199` Where ((lat Between 38.1768916977 And 39.6131083023) And (lng Between -77.9596650363 And -76.1143349637)) ) As FirstCut;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement for this.  You can also move the calculation into the subquery:

```
Select 
     sum(case 
           when rad < 79.85
           then value 
           else 0 end)  1stQuerySum,
     sum(case 
           when rad < 48.57 
           then value 
           else 0 end)  2ndQuerySum
From  ( 
    Select lat, lng, value, 
           acos(0.627895140732*sin(radians(lat)) + 0.778297945677*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-(-1.34454929586))) * 6371 rad
    From `pop_geo_199` 
    Where (
         (lat Between 38.1768916977 And 39.6131083023) And 
         (lng Between -77.9596650363 And -76.1143349637)
    ) 
) As FirstCut
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! That was what I trying to do but couldn't figure out how to move the calculation into the subquery.

Comment: @nucleon -- np, glad I could help!